# OOP/PHP - Selecting out of Database based on ID?

Tags: php, oop

The title may be a little vague, but the question is difficult to word properly.

I'm trying to learn PHP OOP (coming from Procedural) and it's a pain - my main stump is selecting from a databased based on a certain value that is usually passed through the URL (at least in procedural).

For example, user.php?ID=2 - then I could quickly define ID using GET and future queries would use that ID.

Since my OOP classes would be in a seperate file to the main page that includes the html and outputs everything, users won't be submitting the ID to that file. In other words, they'll be going to user.php?ID=2 instead of user_c.php?ID=3 which is the class file.

My question is - how do I pass that ID through to the class? I need to select things out of the database based on the profile that they're viewing, but how do I tell the class that?

My apologies for how badly this is worded.

Comment: Would it be possible once a user visits user.php to then send the ID through to user_c.php? For example, if I visit user.php?ID=2, it would include user_c.php?ID=2 and send the ID through to that file as well?

Comment: Are you asking how to do something like `$record = MyClass::find($_GET['ID'])` ? You should not be referring directly to GET parameters in any class - unless the purpose of that class is e.g. parsing the current url. You need to add some code to the question for it to be on topic here.

Comment: Assuming you instanciated your class, and assuming you have worked (procedurally) with functions in PHP, you can pass your arguments to an object's method like this: `$myResult = $myInstance->myMethod($myArgument);`

Comment: Procedurally, I'd use $ID  = $db->real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripslashes($_GET['ID']))); then all queries would be like WHERE ID = "$ID", but how can I use this in OOP?

Comment: @Lachlan what you'd use procedurally doesn't look procedural. You're using $db as an object.

Comment: when you include a file in another file, you can assume that the contents of the included file are present in the including file. It makes no difference if you include a class or a list of functions, or plain text, or ...

Comment: They rarely intertwine, the majority of following code is procedural.

Comment: @Burki so ID from file A would be included in file B which would hold the classes?

Comment: Yes, pretty much like this. Play with it for a bit and you'll quickly see: including (i.e. putting stuff in different files) helps cleaning up (and reusing), but does not really change your logic.

Comment: @Lachlan I would highly recommend reading a book. [This book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/PHP-Object-Solutions-David-Powers/dp/1430210117?ie=UTF8&SubscriptionId=AKIAIIBINOD46VC3JCLQ&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=1430210117&linkCode=xm2&tag=stackoverfl08-20) might get you started. After getting the basics you might want to read [this](https://github.com/PatrickLouys/no-framework-tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

One would do something like this, `$data` now contains the data returned from the query:

//user_c.php:

```
Class MyUserClass {

   public function getUser($id){
        //Query for user data.
        return $queryData;
   }

}
```

//user.php

```
$userClass = new MyUserClass ();
$data = $userClass->getUser($_GET['ID']);
```

Comment: This answer doesn't show how to "inject" or at least use a database within a class.

Comment: @HamZa it does provide an fair answer to the actual question, though.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, OOP is not that much different than procedural. The main difference is that instead of data and functions which operate on the data you have objects which encapsulate the data as well as the operations which are valid on that data.

However, in its core, OOP does encapsulate procedural programming, with the difference being that the procedural part happens within objects rather than in the application level.

To migrate from procedural to OOP all you need to do is separate your code in parts which are logically connected, in the case of databases what typically happens is each database table has a class (in MVC frameworks this is called a data model).

For example if you have a table called `users` you might have a corresponding `User` class.

```
class User {
      private $id;
      private $alsoOtherProperties;      

      public function __construct($dbconnection, $id) {
          //Load the user from id
      }
      /* Setters and getters and other function here which operate on the user */

}
```

You then create an instance of a user which you construct from the $id given the database connection. The simplest way is do what you're already doing to get the id. From here on your data will be operating on the `User` object rather than on a database result. This way you don't have to worry about changing the database structure since you can just update the model to work with the new structure and the rest of the code will not need altering.

For example, say you want to update the "last logged in" column for a user at the time of log in:

```
//Other code around here
$ID = $db->real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripslashes($_GET['ID'])));

$user = new User($db,ID);

$user->setLastLogin(time()); 

$user->save();
```

In this example there's 2 functions defined in the class `User` in addition to the constructor which is to set the last login time and then update the database row which corresponds to the user. As you can see, this does not have any MySQL specific logic and the underlying code in the user class can update either a MySQL database, a text file, or not do anything (e.g. when just running tests).

**Note:** This is just an example, probably not a very good one at that, you should really really study OOP to learn more about it.

Comment: So the other file will pass $ID to the class, where it's private $id?

Comment: @Lachlan the intention is that the `private $id` as well as all other `private` members of the class will be populated from the data result obtained from the database.

Comment: The result obtained in the database depends on the ID that is passed through the URL to find a specific user's profile.

Comment: Updated with a small example of how you'd potentially use this.

Comment: Far out I hate OOP :(

Comment: Assuming save functio sends it to the db?

Comment: @Lachlan yes that's the assumption. If you don't want your data models to also handle communication with the DB that's also a valid way of doing things but you'd have the create another "library" which handles getting data and initializing the data models.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost you will need to create a simple database class that will handle your queries.

```
class DatabaseQuery {
public $parameters;
public $statement;

function __construct($statement,$parameters)
{
 global $connection; //this will be your new PDO connection details  
$sth = $mysqli->prepare($statement);
$sth ->execute($parameters);
$this -> executedStatement = $sth;


}

function getDetails()
{
    $r_result = $this -> executedStatement;
    $r_result2 = $r_result->fetch();
    $show_result = $r_result2['0'];
    return $show_result;
}
function executeStatementOnly()
{
    return "Action Successful";
}


function __destruct()
{
   //echo "Has been destroyed";
}
}
```

Next you will pick data from user, you will need to sanitize it using this function

```
function clean_data($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
    }
```

Next, pick the data and call your database query class and save or echo the data you are picking.

```
$get_data = clean_data($_GET["id"]);
$user_details = new DatabaseQuery("SELECT column FROM table WHERE id=?",array($get_data));
echo $user_details->getDetails();
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that until now you did something like this:

// user.php

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

$myResult = myDbFunction($id);

function myDbFunction($id) {
    // do something useful
}
```

you can re-write this like that:

// user_c.php:

```
Class MyClass {
    public function myDbFunction($id) {
        $something = "";
        // do something useful
        return $something;
    }
}
```

// user.php:

```
include "user_c.php";

$myClass = new MyClass();

$id = $_GET['id'];

$myResult = $myClass->myDbFunction($id);
```

And that would produce the same results as if you had placed your class in the same file, like this:

// user.php:

```
Class MyClass {
    public function myDbFunction($id) {
        $something = "";
        // do something useful
        return $something;
    }
}


$myClass = new MyClass();

$id = $_GET['id'];

$myResult = $myClass->myDbFunction($id);
```

I assume you know that one of the main reasons for going OOP over procedural is the re-usability as well as information hiding (i.e. sparing a user of your class the need to understand every detail of it, while still allowing them to use it)

You may want to read up on OOP with PHP, and simply play around with it. While there is a slight differece in the two styles, you should get a hang of it quickly.

Once you make sure you understood the single responsibility principle and follow it, you will surely find that OOP has many advantages over procedural programming.

Comment: I'll give this a shot - mainly going to OOP because it's clean and more organised even though I consider it less efficient and more time-wasting.

Comment: @Lachlan On the contrary it saves you time, because it forces you to encapsulate, thus allowing you to re-use. That means, second time round you can use a pre-made class with zero additional effort.

Comment: True, but you end up defining things more than once, in the class and then again in the file using it.

Comment: @Lachlan but that is jsut a few variables, while the bulk of your logic remains in the class.